# PayPal Sandbox developer account drop-down list is empty

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

I created a PayPal developer account and now try to create Sandbox REST API app. But when I want to select "Sandbox developer account" from the drop-down list it is empty and doesn't have any options.
What is the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

well thought it should be a bug on Paypal, I also face this problem sometimes. Then I check the profile of the biz account and see the message "We experienced some issues on our end while creating this Sandbox account. Please delete it and try again." 
I just delete and re-create the biz account few times then it will work as normal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose the account type as Business while creating the test account.Then that created app will apear in your list.

https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/create